# Logon credentials appear for client only

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

My Crystal Report works fine on my computer. But when I create packages and install it on the client's machine, it shows a login page which i have not set for Access or in my code. Why is this showing, and how can I avoid it? I have not used any password for MS access and in vb,net.

This code loads the report:

```
Dim sql1 As String
Dim da1, da2
Dim ds2 As New DataSet
Dim year = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)

da1 = year
da2 = LastDayOfQuarter(Now)

cn1.Open()

sql1 = "Select Query Here"
Dim dscmd As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, cn1)
dscmd.Fill(ds2, "con")
cn1.Close()

Dim objRpt As New CrystalReport3
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds2.Tables(0))
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Comment: Does your report have a subreport?

Comment: Only one report have sub report, out of 5 reports. But its asking for all reports.